# How To: Custom Code In An Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I have code that I wrote that makes donut charts. The JS I wrote has a function on it called "createChart" into which I can pass some JSON data and it will construct a donut chart in HTML from the data.. currently I just plop this into a provided target.

My thought is, if I can create a directive that has my custom code in it, and it returns the HTML for the donut, I can then assign this to the "template" in the directive and have it output that template HTML into my page.

The directive will need to consume data provided from a repeater or other binding in the page template.

Is there an easy way to do this and what are the proper functions to use in the directive ie: is it a .controller, or a .compile, or a .link?

Basically what I want is a directive that I can place all my chart code in, that consumes data potentially in a repeater (my page has rows of charts), and outputs the generated HTML into the page. Being able to use this in a repeater is key.

Here is what I want to do placed in the LINK function below:

```
app.directive("donut", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><b>{{donut.name}}</b></div>',
    scope: {
        donut: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    //compile : compile,
    link : link
};

function compile(){
    console.log(donut)
}

function link(){
    var html = '';
    for(var x = 0 x < donut.values.length; x++){
        html += '<b>' + values[x] + '</b>';
    }
    template = html;
}
});
```

here is what the final HTML should look like:

```
<svg id="svgTarget1" class="svg-target" width="100%" height="150" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
<path d=" M210,150 A60,60 0, 1,0 120.62400768209682,202.31683357523173 L110.83201024279576,219.75577810030896 A80,80 0, 1,1 230,150 z" fill="rgb(92,92,92)" stroke="rgb(92,92,92)" stroke-width="1"></path> 
<path d=" M120.62400768209682,202.31683357523173 A60,60 0, 0,0 155.91452533214658,209.7077749551547 L157.88603377619543,229.6103666068729 A80,80 0, 0,1 110.83201024279576,219.75577810030896 z" fill="rgb(125,125,125)" stroke="rgb(125,125,125)" stroke-width="1"></path> 
<path d=" M155.91452533214658,209.7077749551547 A60,60 0, 0,0 161.24287887514345,208.93723504372133 L164.99050516685793,228.5829800582951 A80,80 0, 0,1 157.88603377619543,229.6103666068729 z" fill="rgb(151,151,151)" stroke="rgb(151,151,151)" stroke-width="1"></path> 
<path d=" M161.24287887514345,208.93723504372133 A60,60 0, 0,0 210,150.00000000000003 L230,150.00000000000003 A80,80 0, 0,1 164.99050516685793,228.5829800582951 z" fill="rgb(211,211,211)" stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" stroke-width="1"></path> 
<path id="node0" d=" M109.58613592203994,80.95856613389196 L94.43093689280492,55.06802843410145 " stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" stroke-width="2"></path> 
<path id="node1" d=" M133.6012676966216,228.30122335469693 L127.45174308285469,257.66418211270826 " stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" stroke-width="2"></path> 
<path id="node2" d=" M161.44979865688956,229.1763986975708 L165.74347315322314,258.86754820915985 " stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" stroke-width="2"></path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: There is this package that already integrates angular and chart.js: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Comment: Sorry, this is my own custom code for custom styled charts, thank you.

Comment: I wrote my own donut chart directive for a project last fall, ended up putting most of the logic in the link portion.  It might not be a best practice, but it functionally met the requirements at the time.

Comment: @theaccordance, how do you get the data from say an ng-repeat into the directive? Currently I can't seem to access the data object 'donut' from the link function... even though the template property reference to the donut data does work.

Comment: change `link()` to `link(scope)` and use `scope.donut` instead of `donut`

Comment: if that works I'll write an official answer, I think that's the missing part now that I'm looking at your code

Comment: ok, that gets closer, now how do I push my generated html from the link function to the page? I tried setting the template property of the $attr object but it no worky.

Comment: That's not how I do it, you'll have to figure that out yourself.  I would encourage you to avoid that pattern and evaluate how to do it using built in angular directives

Comment: @accordance, what is the pattern that you use?

Comment: Instead of pushing content to my template, I use build-in directives like `ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-show`, etc. to change the display of the template depending on the data that is passed

Comment: if you can update your question with an example of what the markup should look like when properly rendered, I might be able to show you how I'd template the directive out

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that about ng-repeat,ng-if etc... :p cant i just push to the template var somehow? It would be sooo much more efficient!

Comment: We'll agree to disagree in terms of efficiency with that approach.  More than one way to skin a cat.  Just push an example markup of what you want and I'll show you how to template it out in my answer

Comment: ok, which svg elements/attributes are you trying to pass values to?

Comment: i pasted in the html at the bottom of the question

Comment: I also discovered you can do this with "element" in the link function, I'm a naughty boy!

Comment: In your directive logic, you have a line where you're appending markup lines with `values[x]`, it's ambiguous where exactly `values[x]` would go in the svg markup you provided

Comment: ok, well, thanks for your help @theaccordance! I decided to go with $element for now since this is the quick and dirty way to getting something on the screen. I'll consider your other options using ng-if etc.

Comment: Alright, I'll just submit an answer w/o the template stuff to mark as correct then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you're passing are accessible through the `scope` object; that object needs to be passed to the directive functions you wish to work with:

```
app.directive("donut", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><b>{{donut.name}}</b></div>',
    scope: {
        donut: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    //compile : compile,
    link : link
};

function compile(){
    console.log(donut)
}

function link(scope){
    var html = '';
    for(var x = 0 x < scope.donut.values.length; x++){
        html += '<b>' + scope.donut.values[x] + '</b>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Will try to give a quick description, that should help you achieve what you want

```
app.directive("donut", function () {
    blah blah blah....
    ......        
    link : function (scope, element) { 
      element              // Use it to manipulate DOM
                           // In your case, your loop

      scope.$apply()       // Use this function to apply changes to the model

      scope.$watch('donut', functionWhatToDo, false/true (object equality check));
      // Use this to watch for model changes and apply changes to your DOM

    }
};
```

Comment: How do I push custom values to the template property of the directive from a link function?

Comment: All values should be defined via scope parameter. The one you have is correct, and it should be accessible via scope variable like - scope.yourParameter

Comment: well i ended up using something liek this with the element parameter. thanks!